# scrbook - Three extremely simple questions about adjustment and font-styling

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, koma-script, scrbook

I have some (probably) really simple questions about a few adjustments in a `scrbook`-documents. Let's take the following minimum-example as the basis for my questions.

---

**Working minimum-example:**

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{                                                          % Horizontal rule above chapter
                \ifnumbered{chapter}
                {\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par}
                {}}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\vspace*{\baselineskip}} % Horizontal rule below chapter

\begin{document}

    \addchap{Foreword}

            \lipsum[1]
            \lipsum[2]
            \lipsum[3]
            \lipsum[4]

    \addchap{Note of thanks}

            \lipsum[1]
            \lipsum[2]
            \lipsum[3]
            \lipsum[4]

    \addchap{Other blabla}

            \lipsum[1]
            \lipsum[2]
            \lipsum[3]
            \lipsum[4]

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Experimental chapter - the first}

            \lipsum[1]
            \lipsum[2]
            \lipsum[3]
            \lipsum[4]

    \chapter{Experimental chapter - the second}

            \lipsum

    \chapter{Experimental chapter - the third}

            \lipsum

    \chapter{Experimental chapter - the fourth}

            \lipsum

\end{document}
```

---

**Question 1:** I want to reduce the vertical space between `chapterprefix` and `chapter` - how can I do that? I think it should be inserted a `\vspace*{-Xpt}` somewhere?

---

**Screenshot to question 1:**

[image]

---

**Question 2:** How can I make the headline of automatically generated elements like `\tableofcontents` look like the `\addchap`-headlines (e.g. *Foreword*, *Note of thanks* or *Other blabla*). Only one line below should be drawn to those automatically generated elements instead of one line above **and** a line below (like it is represented at the numbered-chapters). The same problem exists at `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`, `\printglossary` and `\printbibliography`... All those mentioned and non-numbered (automated) contentelements should be drawn like regular nonumbered-chapters with only one line below.

---

**Screenshots to question 2:**

Numbered chapters (should look like`\chapter` - correct):

[image: Numbered chapters]

Unnumbered-chapters **and** automated elements (should look like `\addchap` - correction for automated elements needed)

[image: Unnumbered chapters]

---

**Question 3:** How to write `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` with sansserif-font instead of serif-font? Is it a clean solution to simply write `\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sf}` - I get some warnings about that?

---

**Screenshot to question 3:**

`\leftmark` and `\rightmark` written in serif-font

[image]

---

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Usually on TeX.SX you ask one question per question...

Comment: `\sf` is deprecated - it is from 2.09 - in LaTeX. Use `\sffamily` instead. The only warnings I get tell you exactly that and tell you exactly how to avoid the warnings, why you should do it differently and what to type ;).

Comment: `\ifnumbered{<section level>}` just tests whether a particular level of sectioning is numbered. It doesn't test whether the current instance is numbered or unnumbered.

Comment: Use `\chapterheadmidvskip` to adjust the skip between the chapter label and the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

Here is a new Suggestion for [KOMA-Script version 3.19 or newer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). There are two new commands: `\chapterlinesformat` and `chapterlineswithprefixformat`. They can be redefined to insert the lines.

With `chapterprefix=true` you can use

```
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{}{\titlerule\par\nobreak}%
  #2#3\par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
```

In case if the lower line should also be inserted if `chapterprefix=false` is used add

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}\par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  chapterprefix=true
]{scrbook}[2015/09/29]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  %innerskip=0pt,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{}{\titlerule\par\nobreak}%
  #2#3\par\nobreak\titlerule%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}\par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\addchap{Foreword}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\addchap{Note of thanks}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\addchap{Other blabla}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{Experimental chapter - the first}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Experimental chapter - the second}
  \lipsum
\chapter{Experimental chapter - the third}
  \lipsum
\chapter{Experimental chapter - the fourth}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer:**
The space between `chapterprefix` and `chapter` is set by `\chapterheadmidvskip`. If there should be no additional space between this two lines you could use either

```
\renewcommand*\chapterheadmidvskip{\par}
```

or the new interface

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter}
```

[image]

---

`\addchap` changes `secnumdepth` locally, so `\ifnumbered{chapter}`. So your definition of `\chapterheadstartvskip` works with `\addchap` but not with `\chapter*`.

One possibility is changing the counter before the TOC/lists headings and reseting it after the TOC/lists headings.

```
\newcounter{savesecnumdepth}
\BeforeTOCHead{%
  \setcounter{savesecnumdepth}{\value{secnumdepth}}%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\partnumdepth}}
\AfterTOCHead{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{savesecnumdepth}}}
```

Note that option `listof=totocnumbered` will not work with this code. But the usage of `listof=totoc` is still possible.

[image]

Or you could redefine the TOC/lists headings using `\addchap` with an empty optional argument to avoid an entry in the table of contents:

```
\deftocheading{toc}{\addchap[]{#1}}
\deftocheading{lof}{\addchap[]{#1}}
```

Or in a loop for all lists known by package `tocbasic`:

```
\makeatletter
  \doforeachtocfile{\deftocheading{\@currext}{\addchap[]{##1}}}
\makeatother
```

But in that case you can not use the values `totoc` and `leveldown` for option `listof`.

**Update**

Maybe it is easier to insert the first line in `\chapterformat` instead in `\chapterheadstartvskip`.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  innerskip=0pt,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}\par}
\preto\chapterformat{\IfUsePrefixLine{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\titlerule}{}}
\preto\chapterheadendvskip{\titlerule}
```

---

To get a sans-serif font in the page header and footer use

```
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
```

---

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  innerskip=0pt,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}\par}
\preto\chapterformat{\IfUsePrefixLine{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\titlerule}{}}
\preto\chapterheadendvskip{\titlerule}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\addchap{Foreword}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\addchap{Note of thanks}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\addchap{Other blabla}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{Experimental chapter - the first}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Experimental chapter - the second}
  \lipsum
\chapter{Experimental chapter - the third}
  \lipsum
\chapter{Experimental chapter - the fourth}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```